# How to link libatomic in cmake?

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-ndk, .so

I try to link the library in my cmake file as follow:

```
find_library( atomic-lib atomic )
target_link_libraries( mylib ${atomic-lib})
```

but it still get an error

```
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:atomic-lib
```

Comment: I believe that **android.toolchain.cmake** always adds `libatomic.so` to your target

Comment: It does. @mars-rong: if you're not seeing this, update your NDK.